# Difference in fs watch methods

Tags: node.js, watch

What is the defference between methods of `node.js` file system watching:

- `watch(filename,[, options],(filename) => {} )` (*node-watch* package)
- `fs.watch(filename[, options][, listener])`
- `fs.watchFile(filename[, options], listener)`

(*add more if any*)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was looking for info on this exact question and came across [this post.](http://tech.nitoyon.com/en/blog/2013/10/02/node-watch-impl/)

#### *- Blog post in a nutshell:*

#### `fs.watch()`

- is a newer API and recommended.
- uses native watching functions supported by OS, so doesn't waste CPU on waiting.
- doesn't support all platforms such as AIX and Cygwin.

#### `fs.watchFile()`

- is an old API and not recommended.
- calls stat() periodically, so uses CPU even when nothing changes.
- runs on any platform.

#### *- Not in the blog post:*

#### `node-watch()`

I haven't used node-watch myself, but, by looking at it, I can see it extends fs.watch() and adds recursive functionality. fs.watch() allows you to watch a directory for changes, but to watch all directories below would require separate calls. If I had to guess, (I've not tried it) these might be the same:

`fs.watch(./project)`

`fs.watch(./project/assets)`

`fs.watch(./project/lib)`

Or

`node-watch(./project, { recursive: true })`